# Ошибка при написании автотестов: java: несовместимые типы: int нельзя преобразовать в java.time.Duration

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, автоматизация

Изучаю автотесты Java, selenium, maven, junit.

Проблема в несовместимости типов: `int` нельзя преобразовать в `java.time.Duration`.

```
java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.time.Duration
```

Код:

```
public PageBase(WebDriver driver) { /* 4. конструктор создан */
    this.driver = driver;
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30,0); /* 5. добавим драйвер wait */
}
```

Также у меня прописано ожидание появления элемента на странице

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Этот код вынесен в аннотацию `@BeforeEach`.

И здесь тоже ошибка:

```
java: no suitable method found for implicitlyWait(int,int,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)
    
method org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Timeouts.implicitlyWait(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    
method org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Timeouts.implicitlyWait(java.time.Duration) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем причина?

Answer (score 1):

У класса [`WebDriverWait`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) есть конструктор (и ещё 2) [`WebDriverWait​(WebDriver driver, java.time.Duration timeout, java.time.Duration sleep)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html#%3Cinit%3E(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,java.time.Duration,java.time.Duration)), принимает три параметра. Вы передаёте три аргумента, но несоответствующих типов. java видет, что тип аргумента 30 (`int`) не соответсвует требуемому (`Duration`) и пытается выполнить преобразование (по своим внутренним правилам), но терпет неудачу - получаете соответствующее сообщение.

У [`WebDriver.Timeouts`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) есть два перегруженных метода `implicitlyWait`:

1. [`implicitlyWait​(long time, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))
2. [`implicitlyWait​(java.time.Duration duration)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait(java.time.Duration))

Вы передаёте три параметра в метод, из-за того, что не совпадает количество аргументов и выдаётся сообщение, что нет подходящего метода.

Пример как работать с ожиданиями можно посмотреть в документации на странице [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/).

При выборе метода, например `implicitlyWait​` обратите внимание на то, что первый `implicitlyWait​(long, TimeUnit)` помечен как `Deprecated`, т.е он не рекомендован к использоваеию. Вместо него в документации советуют использовать `implicitlyWait​(Duration)`.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.  С ожиданием разобралась. С конструктором немного непонятно как исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена следующими правками:

Код

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

изменен на

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
```

Код

```
public PageBase(WebDriver driver) { /* 4. конструктор создан */
    this.driver = driver;
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30,0); /* 5. добавим драйвер wait */
}
```

изменен на

```
public PageBase(WebDriver driver) { /* 4. конструктор создан */
        this.driver = driver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30)); /* 5. добавим драйвер wait */
    }
```

После этого открылся браузер, переход на сайт и клик по нужному элементу.

А целом тест  провалился - нужно искать причину.